# How can insert amount to class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a bank account system in order to get experience at object oriented programming. But when I try to add some money I couldn't understand what to do. Please help me!

```
class Account():


    def __init__(self, owner='Unknown', balance=0):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += self.amount
        print('Deposit Accepted')

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance >= self.amount:
            self.balance -= self.amount
            print('Withdrawal Accepted')
        else:
            print('Funds Unvailable!')

    def __str__(self):
        return(f'Account owner: {self.owner} \nAccount balance: ${self.balance}')

acct1 = Account('Bati', 999)
acct1.deposit(1)
acct1.balance
```

The error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-03ccc6c72dd3> in <module>
     21 
     22 acct1 = Account('Bati', 999)
---> 23 acct1.deposit(1)
     24 acct1.balance

<ipython-input-21-03ccc6c72dd3> in deposit(self, amount)
      7 
      8     def deposit(self, amount):
----> 9         self.balance += self.amount
     10         print('Deposit Accepted')
     11 

AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'amount'
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: `self.balance += self.amount` should probably be `self.balance += amount` though, and the same with the other method. `amount` is a parameter, not a member of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite the methods without self before the input parameters of the functions:

```
class Account():

    def __init__(self, owner='Unknown', balance=0):
        self.owner = owner
    self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        print('Deposit Accepted')

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance >= amount:
            self.balance -= amount
            print('Withdrawal Accepted')
        else:
            print('Funds Unvailable!')

    def __str__(self):
        return(f'Account owner: {self.owner} \nAccount balance: (self.balance}')

acct1 = Account('Bati', 999)
acct1.deposit(1)
acct1.balance
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use self.amount. You are passing the amount value as a parameter to the function. It is not a variable of the class.

```
class Account():


    def __init__(self, owner='Unknown', balance=0):
        self.owner = owner
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        print('Deposit Accepted')

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance >= amount:
            self.balance -= amount
            print('Withdrawal Accepted')
        else:
            print('Funds Unvailable!')

    def __str__(self):
        return(f'Account owner: {self.owner} \nAccount balance: ${self.balance}')

acct1 = Account('Bati', 999)
acct1.deposit(1)
acct1.balance
```

Here is an updated code which works

Comment: Thank you too but another one has also answered. But thank you too!!